# iOS app image / icon bit depth

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

It's a first time I am posting **iPhone app** to Apple. After much research I have not been able to find out answer to my questions and I don't want my app to be bounced back due to a silly thing. I am referring link below to create images/icons:

[icons/image diamensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

The 2nd last line on link says that "The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits—that is, 8 bits each for red, green, and blue—plus an 8-bit alpha channel." Does it mean that total bit depth should be 32?

I have some of the images in my app whose bit depth is less that 32. My question is that **are there any chances to get my app rejected because of this?** Is it must to have images/icons to be of bit depth 32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last icons that I submitted were all described as "24 bit" and didn't have an alpha channel.  My app was accepted.

(It was submitted and accepted in February of 2014)

Looking back at all of our icons and screens, they are all 24 bit.  We've submitted a half dozen apps 3 or 4 times each.  None of them were failed or even questioned.